# List of type names visible at a given position

Tags: c++, libclang

I need a way to programatically retrieve a list of all type names that are visible at a given position in a C++ source, even when the source is incomplete (eg. being edited).

I understand LibClang is probably already creating such a list under the hoods in the [Code Completion](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/group__CINDEX__CODE__COMPLET.html) module, but as far as I can tell from the specs, it won't expose it.

Now, I'm not afraid to get my hands dirty with Clang source, but before I set about hacking it, is there an easy way that I'm missing to get what I need? Alternatively, is there a different library or a *command line* tool that lets me get the list?

Comment: What do you mean by won't expose it?  Can't you get all those interfaces from `libclang`?

Comment: I just meant that the code completion module doesn't conveniently have a function that returns the list of all visible types, although I'm pretty sure it would be possible to write one given the infrastructure it already has.